# Categorize favorites

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I have been using Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites from a long time. Specifically in Stack Overflow, I have favorite questions which I want to refer later. The list is growing. It is difficult to find any particular favorite.

It would be nice if you allow user to define favorite categories and while clicking favorite, user can select the category under which the favorite to put.

If I want to see my favorite questions under [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), it should show all favorites in this tag.

Answer (score 5):

You can already search through your favorites using the standard search box by using the operator `infavorites:me`, and you can further refine that to questions about ASP.NET-MVC by adding the tag search operator `[asp.net-mvc]`, like so:

[`infavorites:me [asp.net-mvc]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Ame+[asp.net-mvc])

Adding a categorization system would just be duplicating functionality that already exists in another form.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my notice.

Comment: Hmm. I tried what you suggested. Using those operators is a bit cryptic but serves the same purpose I desired. Not easy though. More typing required.

Comment: It might not be a bad idea to introduce a UI element to make this functionality more clear. Our search has gotten a lot better, but I feel like we don't surface this sort of thing as well as we could.